# How to have Semantic URLs for generated html pages in meteor?

Tags: javascript, url, meteor

When using python and Django I recall there being a way to use views with the http requests to make is so there would be a generated url for any webpage that was generated, say like a user profile or something like that. Is there a way for me to do this when using meteor JS? Any help would be great, just a link to an article would do, I cant seem to find anything about it.

Comment: You are probably looking for [Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/meteor/5119/routing) capability. There is Iron Router (described in the linked doc) and also [Flow Router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router)

Comment: @ghybs I know how to route, I use flow router. What I am asking is how to have a url generate opposed to me type it in manually in the code

Comment: oh ok my bad, sorry for the misunderstanding :-) Then you are looking for [Semantic URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL), aka [friendly slugs](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=friendly%20slugs)

Comment: @ghybs thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything out of the box that will generate URL's for you, since this functionality is tied to routing (and Meteor core doesn't provide routing). Since you're using FlowRouter, you might want to take a look at the [arillo:flow-router-helpers](https://atmospherejs.com/arillo/flow-router-helpers) package. This package won't auto generate URL's for you, but it will give you URL helpers that you can leverage inside your Template's (Blaze), to make it easier to generate URL's for links. A few quick examples from their docs:

**`{{pathFor}}`**

```
<a href="{{pathFor '/post/:id' id=_id}}">Link to post</a>
<a href="{{pathFor 'postRouteName' id=_id}}">Link to post</a>
<a href="{{pathFor '/post/:id/comments/:cid' id=_id cid=comment._id}}">Link to comment in post</a>
<a href="{{pathFor '/post/:id/comments/:cid' id=_id cid=comment._id query='back=yes&more=true'}}">Link to comment in post with query params</a>
```

**`{{urlFor}}`**

Like `pathFor` but returns absolute URL's.

```
{{urlFor '/post/:id' id=_id}}
```

**`{{linkTo}}`**

```
{{#linkTo '/posts/'}}
  Go to posts
{{/linkTo}}
```